# What is the normal range of platelet count and does this differ with age and sex?

Tags: blood, research, epidemiology, hematology, platelet-count

I am trying to study the normal range of platelet counts and there are various sources out there on the internet on this topic. The article [What do high or low platelet count levels mean?](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/322726#Normal-platelet-levels) suggests that **the normal range is 150,000–450,000 per microliter of blood**. It is also mentioned that some studies suggest that normal platelet levels should take into account other variables, such as a person’s age and sex. This range is found in most sources on the internet. However, another article [What is a Normal Platelet Count?](https://www.oneblood.org/media/blog/platelets/what-is-a-normal-platelet-count.stml) suggests that **the average platelet count range is 157,000-371,000 (for women) and 135,000-317,000 (for men) per microliter of blood**.

The fact that different range is mentioned in different sources prompted me to ask the question regarding the normal range of platelet count. Also, I am willing to know whether the normal range differs with a person's age and sex (the research paper linked in the first article is: [Platelet count and aging](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4040891/pdf/0990953.pdf)).

Comment: The short answer is yes, platelet count is significantly influenced by age and sex. In my employer's health system, the reference range for platelet count is reported based on age. To usefully answer your question for your application, we would need to have some additional details.

Comment: @IanCampbell Sure! please let me know what additional details I need to provide.